# Как правильно произвести инициализацию драйвера SQLITE JDBC в JAVA

Tags: java, sqlite

```
Не могу никак подключить драйвер JDBC. Выходит сообщение о том, что не нашел класс. Хотя в зависимости все нормально, GRADLE сам скачал библиотеку. Что делать ума не приложу.
```

[image: Код]
![Код][1]
[image: Зависимость]
![Зависимость][2]
[image: Зависимость]
![Зависимость][3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что ваш `sqlite-jdbc` не находится в `classpath`.

Откройте структуру проекта (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S), там перейдите в Artifacts.
В папке `WEB-INF` создайте папку `lib` и туда положите библиотеку `sqlite-jdbc`. Теперь она будет в `classpath`.

[Пример (изображение)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJhLT.png)

Также рекомендую регистрировать драйвер следующим способом:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
```

Где `new Driver()` - именно тот SQLite драйвер.

При использовании этого способа регистрации драйвера, у вас не будет ошибки на уровне выполнения программы, только на уровне компиляции, что более эффективно.